# Dark Mode/Light Mode settings not showing up in Assets.xcassets for Xamarin.ios in Visual Studio for Windows

Tags: xamarin.ios, ios-darkmode

Are the Dark Mode/Light Mode settings available in Assets.xcassets in Visual Studio for Windows?

I've installed VS 2019 version 16.3.5 on PC and XCode version 11.1(11A1027) on Mac.

I've seen examples showing a screen with these settings but I don't see them when I open my Assets catalog on VS for Windows, however I do see them on VS for Mac.

Comment: Hi , after refering to [Assets for Light and Dark Modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/ios/page-safe-area-layout) ,I think vs for windows now can not do that . Hope next version of vs for windows will support it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Unfortunately** , now this can not support in vs for windows , even in the latest version of it.

After refering to [Assets for Light and Dark Modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/ios/page-safe-area-layout) ,it only shows the view of vs for Mac , no view for windows.

[image]

I think vs for windows now can not do that . Hope next version of vs for windows will support it .

Answer (score 2):

I have VS 2019 16.3.10 installed. I've used the appearance property to change the Dark Mode/Light Mode settings

[image]